# Pop up blocker in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm facing the pop up blocker issue while open the popup window from parent button Click.

[Error Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap3fq.png)

I tried the following things but I'm facing the same Error.

1.In internet option->privacy tab I unchecked "Turn On block pop up" option.
2.under security tab I tried with uncheck the Enable protected mode.
3.added my website in the popup allowing site also under "turn on block popup"

Note :

1.I'm able to open the popup by manually without any interruption.
2.I'm using IE and C# .

Comment: Seems the application `Microsoft Dynamic CRM` you are trying to launch will need the popup blocker to be removed. Try using a specific `Browser Profile` instead with all the required settings.

Comment: @DebanjanB Could you please elaborate liitle bit on this pls ?

Comment: It's quite clear from the message that `popup` needs to be enabled. So create a new `Chrome`/`Firefox` `Profile`, configure the `Profile` to accept `Popups`. Now while you initiate the `WebDriver` instance either use the created profile to access your application or else `Selenium` will scoop up a new `Profile` as per your configurations when you initialize a new `Session`.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the capabilities for IE Like below.

```
caps.setCapability("browserstack.ie.enablePopups", "true");
```

Comment: InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapablity("browserstack.ie.enablePopups",true);

IwebDriver ie=new InternetExplorerDriver(iewebDriverLocation,options,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));